# Ratings Delete function using zoo:visitors

Tags: ee2, add-on

I'm trying to use the delete function in [Solspace's Ratings addon](http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/delete/):

It's passing the correct `rating_id`, but what seems to be happening is that since I'm using Zoo Visitor, it doesn't seem to be recognising me as the author of the item I'm trying to delete (or something like that)?

How can I turn off the function that checks this?

Comment: The official support forum for Solspace Rating is here http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewforum/12/

Answer (score 1):

Disregard -- I found how to do this, was clearly written in the documentation I just didn't read.  Thanks.

Comment: For future visitors it would be nice if you could update your answer with a brief overview of how you solved the problem.